# Set one element above another and have width of both the element equal

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

**I want to set the text field above the black image and i want the width of text field should be equal to image**.

I dont want to put hardcoded dimensions. Also both the blocks should qually cover the screen horizontally.

Here is my code `

```
            <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/RL_childLeft1"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

                <com.ism.eshita.incentivemanagmentsystem.Speedometer.Speedometer
                    android:id="@+id/Speedometer"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="#000000"
                    custom:currentSpeed="100"
                    custom:maxSpeed="300" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_bg1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@color/PrimaryDark2"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="BG"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_performance1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@color/PrimaryDark2"

                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                        android:text="Performance"
                        android:textColor="@color/white" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                >

                <com.ism.eshita.incentivemanagmentsystem.Speedometer.Speedometer
                    android:id="@+id/Speedometer2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="#000000"
                    custom:currentSpeed="100"
                    custom:maxSpeed="300" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_bg2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@color/PrimaryDark2"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="BG"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_performance2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@color/PrimaryDark2"

                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                        android:text="Performance"
                        android:textColor="@color/white" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This is the screen shot [link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/CqXrl.png)